# java.lang.VerifyError with paho Android Service

Tags: android, mqtt, messagebroker, paho

For days and i have been trying to get the `paho android service` working. I have downloaded it from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/) and i followed the steps provided in the website to unpack the `GIT` contents. and regarding the `Paho Java Client` i downloaded it from [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/) as a zipped fil, and the contenets f the zipped file, i copied them into the `libs` folder which i created inside the `org.eclipse.paho.android.service` folder.

Now, when i import the `paho android service` which contains the `org.eclipse.paho.android.service`, `org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample` and the `org.eclipse.paho.android.service.test` folder into eclipse, the projects are nor marked with exclamation ark nor a red X mark, but when I run the App, i receive the below `logcat` output. To solve it, i checked some questions related to the `java.lang.VerifyError` error but the problem still exist.

**logcat**:

```
11-12 17:24:12.991: E/AndroidRuntime(12118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 17:24:12.991: E/AndroidRuntime(12118): Process: org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample, PID:  
12118
11-12 17:24:12.991: E/AndroidRuntime(12118): java.lang.VerifyError: 
org/eclipse/paho/android/service/sample/ClientConnections$LongClickItemListener
11-12 17:24:12.991: E/AndroidRuntime(12118):    at 
org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample.ClientConnections.onCreate(ClientConnections.java:82)
11-12 17:24:12.991: E/AndroidRuntime(12118):    at     
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
```